# Itext PDF escape characters issues

Tags: java, escaping, itext

Why itext converts `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt;`,  `&` to `&amp;` and so on please suggest a what should I do to fix it with itext1.4.8

Code

```
PdfTable table  = new PdfTable();
BaseFont baseF = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD,BaseFont.WINANSI,BaseFont.EMBEDED);
Font f= new Font(baseF,Font.DESFAULTSIZE,Font.NORMAL);
PdfCell cell = new PdfCell(new Paragraph("Gyet should not be > 5 & should not be < 1",f))
```

now when PDF is created is resolves as describe above

Comment: Learn how to use commas. :)

Comment: Have you looked it up on <insert favorite search engine here>? What about some code?

Comment: This question already has an answer here :: That is for c# I think I want java solution but I try that one as well (used similar java classes) but still same issue